# What is the time complexity of this loop where it only runs one time?

Tags: while-loop, time-complexity

This questions was asked in Expedia Summer Intern test
We need to find the time complexity of this while loop?

```java
int a=1;
while(a<3){
   a=a+2;
}
```

Comment: a single n times loop, time complexity is O(n)

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions , and only use a language tag for a language that the code is actually using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is O(1)
this is exactly one iteration.
a exceeds the bound of the loop which is 3 (after one iteration);

Answer (score 0):

Since no input dimension affects the number of operations, the asymptotic complexity is constant.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity for this code is `O(1)`. Because it is a **single loop** with **finite number of iterations**.

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/